# TDengine create table number not as expected using schemaless in taosBenchmark

Tags: tdengine

I want to create 10000 child tables but after I successfully execute taosBenchmark program, I use taos shell with  command
 `select count(tbname) from stb;`
but the result shows 255 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Schemaless is special when create childtable, in taosBenchmark, you cannot specify the child table name when using schemaless insertion, the table name is randomly generated with UUID when the tags is detected as new, otherwise, it will insert into the same child table. I think in your case you just set the one tag with tinyint/unsigned tinyint data type.